# mPDF importing page from another document

Tags: php, mpdf

I'm trying to create PHP document in PHP using mPDF library. I want to import the last page from another PDF document. According to document I use, the imported page is too small (it's on 1/3 of the page) or too big (I see only part of the page). Is there any way to make it fit?

My code:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('', '', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'L');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->AddPage();
$mpdf->SetImportUse(); 

$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile('application/views/default/pdf/nabidka-design.pdf');
$tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount);

$mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId); 
$mpdf->Output();
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You have to set page format for output PDF file like this:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', '8', '', 10, 10, 7, 7, 10, 10);
```

Change 'A4' on your PDF source file format.